Initialize a default microphone with pyaudio
I am using PyAudio for a project and I am using my system's built in Audio Monitor as input so I can capture system sound on Linux Mint.
The Audio Monitor doesn't show up as the default input until I open the volume control app (or any app that uses a microphone like Audacity) and once I do, PyAudio recognizes it as the default device. However, I do not want to open another app every time I want to use my project. I would like to have it 'initializes' the system Audio Monitor when I start the project so it could be recognized as the default.
I assume it's possible somehow, since Audacity can do it, but I am not sure how I would go about it in Python. When I don't open any other apps the default is set to my microphone. Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated, thank you.
I have tried listing all the devices with PyAudio to see if it would show up on there, but it doesn't. It seems that it needs to be activated somehow, and apps like Audacity somehow do that.
